# Flask Dynamic Route For Table Name

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently using Flask with SQLAlchemy ORM with MySQL. I was
wondering if is possible to create dynamics routes that is mapped to
table name.

**For Example:**
User would pass in the table name as part of the route, and the function
would query based on the argument.

```py
@blueprint_db.route('/<string:table>', methods=['POST'])
@blueprint_db.route('/<string:table>/', methods=['POST'])
def read_table(table: str):
    data = table.query.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy is a ORM so It need a model to map the result query to model. In your case, I suggest create a dictionary with key is table name and value is model name. After that, when request come, the service get model from dict and query.

Example:

```
from src.models.users import User
from src.models.roles import Role

db_models = {
    "user": User,
    "role": Role,
}

@blueprint_db.route('/<string:table>', methods=['POST'])
@blueprint_db.route('/<string:table>/', methods=['POST'])
def read_table(table: str):
    data = db_models[table].query.all()
```

Comment: thank you for the information @TanThien, i will give your method a try, though I would say it will be hard to scale if you have a large amount of models...with that said, I found you can use `model = db.Model.metadata.tables.get(table)` to get the table, and execute it with `db.session.execute(model.select())`, but the issue is, it doesn't return a key value pair as mentioned in documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#the-select-sql-expression-construct

Comment: i also encountered issue when trying the declarative approach with the models

Comment: @YTKme oh, with a large amount of models. I have a idea to solve. After you get the table name by `db.Model.metadata.tables.get(table)`, load package by table name. `model_path = importlib.import_module('src.models.'+str(table))` `model_table = getattr(model_path, str(table))`  final `print(model_table.query.all())`. You must use table name in database same as class name. Now, You have target object model to avoid the issue `doesn't return a key value pair `

Comment: But, I still want you to register all model to dictionary although it will be many models. The server can handle query in table that has in dict, avoid a brute force attack that can use your api to get information from some system table